# Zend_Db_Table - Associative Array Instead Of Object

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

The following line:

```
$select = $table->select();
$select->where('approved = 1');
$result = $table->fetchRow($select);
```

Returns an object. What I would like is to get an associative array instead.

I know that Zend_Db has fetchAssoc() method for that but is something similar also in the Zend_Db_Table (I tried fetchAssoc() but it doesn't work, I haven't found anything in the documentation)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$result = $table->fetchRow($select)->toArray();
```

Both `Zend_Db_Table_Row` and `Zend_Db_Table_Rowset` have a `toArray()` method.  A Row is returned as an associative array, and a Rowset is returned as a simple (ordinal) array of associative arrays.

Answer (score 2):

To further Bill's answer, if you wanted the Rowset returned as an associative array (rather than ordinal) the only choice appears to be Zend_Db (as you alluded to):

```
$db     = $table->getAdapter();
$select = $table->select();
$select->where('approved = 1');
$result = $db->fetchAssoc($select);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Db_Table');
class SomeTable extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract{

protected $_name = 'sometable';

public function getAssoc($where = null, $order = null, $count = null, $offset = null){
    if (!($where instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Select)) {
        $select = $this->select();

        if ($where !== null) {
            $this->_where($select, $where);
        }

        if ($order !== null) {
            $this->_order($select, $order);
        }

        if ($count !== null || $offset !== null) {
            $select->limit($count, $offset);
        }

    } else {
        $select = $where;
    }   
    return $this->getAdapter()->fetchAssoc($select);        
}
}
```

Then in your code:

```
$this->some_table = new SomeTable();
//Get and print some row(s) 
$where = $this->some_table->getAdapter()->quoteInto('primarykey_name = ?', $primarykey_value);
print_r($this->somes_table->getAssoc($where));

//Get and print all rows 
print_r($this->areas_table->getAssoc());
```